# Add (Year) to footnotes in BibLaTeX-authortitle

Tags: biblatex, authoryear, customize

I am really happy with the authortitle-style provided by BibLatex. I am using it to cite in footnotes (with ibid enabled). The first mentions of a citation look something like this:

```
1 Medina, Cybernetic Revolutionaries, S. 127.
```

Yet I would like to give my reader a direct glimpse at the year in which to entry has been written.

```
1 Medina, Cybernetic Revolutionaries (2011), S. 127.
```

It does not need to reappear when in "ibid."-mentions, it can stay like "vgl. ebd., S. 128". Nothing else has to change.

Is there a simple way to do it, or do you have a style in mind that enables this (or similar) by default?

If it is to complicated to implement because it needs different commands for every entry type, I would also be okay with the following general rule, where the Year appears in brackets directly after the author:

```
1 Medina (2011), Cybernetic Revolutionaries, S. 127.
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome. // Please provide some relevant code. Things of interest are at least: a) your .bib-file (one entry or so), b) packages you use, c) styles you use for citation and bibliography. You may provide it all with a short but complete code, starting at \documentclass, until \end{document}. We always welcome code, we can copy, compile and see your approach and/or problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the following redefinition of the `cite` bibmacro from [`authortitle-ibid.cbx` (ll. 18-26)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/05e0b879993adfed43b0213b42f18eade46e9b7e/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authortitle-ibid.cbx#L18-L26). The idea is to add a new bibmacro that prints the date.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle-ibid]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{cite:date}{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibparens{##1}}%
  \printdate
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
        \setunit*{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:date}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[381]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[382]{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite[33]{worman}
sit \autocite{sigfridsson}
amet \autocite[56]{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Sigfridsson und Ryde, „Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments“ (1998), S. 381. 2 Ebd., S. 382. 3 Worman, Cast of Character (2002), S. 33. 4 Sigfridsson und Ryde, „Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments“ (1998). 5 Geer, „Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music“ (1985), S. 56.]